# some svg icons on web app displays wrong when deployed to vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

So my portfolio is deployed on vercel. It was developed using Nextjs, Tailwindcss  and Framer Motion

On the Windows version everything works well but on Mobile i noticed the some svg icons becomes way larger than it should be. i will drop a libk to my portfolio, Please view with Mobile to see the issue im talking about i have gone through my app i cant find the problem actually when inspect it from my pc it works well. It only happens when the web app is view with a phone..

so here is the Link any one know how to fix this? : https://my-portfolio-phi-red.vercel.app/